# converting turkish characters

Tags: php, utf

i am getting data from website and i am saving to xml file. i want to replace all turkish characters because if not, i am getting weird characters when i access the data from xml.

i used this code

```
$html = str_replace("ç", "Bccedil;", $html);
$html = str_replace("Ç", "BCcedil;", $html);
$html = str_replace("ö", "Bouml;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("Ö", "BOuml;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("ý", "B#305;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("Ý", "B#304;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("ü", "Buuml;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("Ü", "BUuml;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("ð", "B#287;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("Ð", "B#286;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("þ", "B#351;" , $html);
$html = str_replace("Þ", "B#350;" , $html);

$myFile = "test.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $html);
fclose($fh);
```

it is weird that nothing changed after this code. if i want to replace for example 'a' to 'c' it works. but for turkish characters it doesnt work.

Data i get :

> İstanbul Taksim’de başlayan ve yurt sathına yayılan olaylar

When i access :

> Ýstanbul Taksim’de baþlayan ve yurt sathýna yayýlan olaylar

Comment: can you paste some turkish sentence under your post?And paste the so called weird characters too

Comment: Are you sure that these characters are not already broken before calling `str_replace`?

Comment: @enenen yes i am sure. because before i save data to xml, i also print it to check. Printed data is exactly true

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do this when creating the xmldocument

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
```

Comment: after where am i gonna use $dom?

Comment: Share your code, I am not sure if you are reading the xml into a DOMDocument or not